# Percentage change in value or values?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The charts are from my book published by Cambridge University Press. Any chance the book is wrong?

In the tile of the table, I think the singular "value" should be used.

> Percentage change in **value**

But the book uses the plural:

> Percentage change in **values**

[image]

Comment: We're not supposed to use images in questions. Anyway, isn't this prices? Exports have prices, not values, in economics in English.